# Path shortener with MFC

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

I need to display paths in the context menu in my app and need to find a way to shorted them. For instance, what Microsoft apps do in their "Recently Used" list, if the original path is `c:\ClientName\ProjectName\ProgramName\ComponentName\SomeFileName.cpp` I need it to be converted into something like `c:\ClientName\...\SomeFileName.cpp`.

So I'm curious if there's any built-in means to do this with C++/MFC or maybe a WinAPI?

Comment: `DrawTextEx` with the `DT_MODIFYSTRING` and `DT_PATH_ELLIPSIS` flags.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: But I'm not drawing anything. I need to transform the string itself.

Comment: OK, nevermind. I might've found what I need: [PathCompactPathEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773578(v=vs.85).aspx). I little buggy according to MSDN comments, but, oh well...

Comment: The `DT_MODIFYSTRING` flag **does** transform the string. It depends what you want to do, but `PathCompactPathEx` compacts to a specified number of characters, whereas `DrawTextEx` compacts to a specified number of *pixels*. You can draw to an offscreen DC if you don't want to actually render anything visible.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Interesting. I didn't know that. I also found that if one needs to shorten string by pixel width, you can use [PathCompactPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773575(v=vs.85).aspx), which unfortunately has that moronic Windows Shell limitation of `MAX_PATH` length.

Answer (score 2):

Use [PathCompacPathEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773578%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that will truncate a path by replacing path components with ellipses.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you already found the answer. But putting the answer here is the preferred way.

Answer (score -1):

There is Win32 API to get short path name called GetShortPathName, read below. It may help.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364989(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: `GetShortPathName` returns old-style (DOS) 8.3 file paths. It has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: @c00000fd, *On many file systems, a file name will contain a tilde (~) within each component of the name that is too long to comply with 8.3 naming rules.* Of course it's not guaranteed to work for the reasons stated in the documentation. But if it does, it should return a shorter string, just like you asked for.

Comment: @chris: You have a funny logic ;)